# trying to run HAPI TestPanel source code

Tags: java, hl7, hapi

I was trying to run HAPI TestPanel source code and it refers to an enum called `Hl7V2EncodingTypeEnum` located at a package `ca.uhn.hl7v2.testpanel.xsd.Hl7V2EncodingTypeEnum`;

The problem is I couldn't find the package at `xsd` even on Github.
Where can I get it?

Answer (score 2):

It is a generated file. It is part of the XSD you can find at for example https://github.com/hapifhir/hapi-hl7v2/blob/master/hapi-testpanel/src/main/resources/testpanel.xsd , which should also be part of the source code you have on your system. The Maven pom has a JAXB plugin which will generate all the necessary source files.

So, running `mvn clean install` should trigger the generation of the files. If you're using an IDE it should have Maven integration features that allow you to generate sources.